# Apache2 - 403 Forbidden, chmod/chown/chgrp doesn't make any difference

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, http-status-code-403

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, 32, PHP, Apache2. I have a folder which is universally readable: /home/ashesh/commonfloor.com/developmentBranch11.0/html - and that's what apache2 is pointing to. commonfloor.com is also universally readable, executable. So are all the folders inside it.

However much I try, I can see that apache2 is throwing a 403 forbidden error. It throws a permission denied for favicon.ico, more particularly:

```
[Mon Jul 02 12:18:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Mon Jul 02 12:18:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied
```

And I've tried a chown www-data and chgrp www-data on these folders and nothing has helped. What might be the issue?

Comment: Show us more of your server config. The error only does not help.

Comment: Ok, here's apache2.conf: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8856637/apache2.conf
And here's 000-default: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8856637/000-default

Comment: Thank you for adding also the 000 file. I just wanted to ask for it. Let me try to answer...

Comment: Desperation move: `strace -p` the apache process, do the request, kill the strace, and read the strace output to see what happened. (This may be hard to get right if there are a ton of apache processes.)

Comment: Is /home/ashesh coming from an NFS server?  Depending on the NFS server configuration, root processes (apache) could get permission errors.

Comment: @AlanCurry I reinstalled Apache2, after a complete purge. I noticed that /etc/apache2 wasn't removed at all. Suspecting something might be wrong in it and wanting to do a fresh install, I removed /etc/apache2. I reinstalled apache2 and to my shock and disbelief, I saw that /etc/apache2 wasn't recreated while it should have been.
And now, I can't even start the service.

Comment: @BrianSwift No, apache and /home come from the same machine.

Comment: can apache read /home and /home/ashesh?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the reason right now. You use a very log path maybe there is any subfolder where the permissions are set in such a way where the apache does not be allowed to access. Try the default path like `/var/www/myproject` and create a softlink from your home directory to that folder.

Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't work. I've tried that without any success.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had to give up on this. Checked out the code afresh inside /var/www/commonfloor.com [rwX]